# OpenMP parallel recursion with branching

Tags: c++, c, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to speed up my calculations using OpenMP, but I am not sure whether parallelization will work with branching.

Here's the code (stripped the unnecessary parts):

```
if (flag) {
    int val;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
       val = 2 + recursion(i, flag = 0));
    }
    return val;
} else {
    int val;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
       val = 1 + recursion(i, flag = 1);
    }
    return val;
}
```

I am not sure how to parallelize this function.

Comment: You should do some digging into the topic of OpenMP's *tasks* which seem, based on your outline, likely to be apposite.

Comment: How big is ```size``` in the top layer of invocation?

Comment: @Homer512 On the top layer, it's 40

Comment: I would try de-recursing the function first

Comment: if you provide a [mre] we can show you how to speed it up (e.g. how to remove the branch, how to parallelize, etc.). Is your goal to create a code as fast as possible or to learn OpenMP?

Comment: when you call `recursion(i,...)`, what is the dummy argument that correspond to the actual first argument?

Comment: A general strategy in such cases would be to keep track of the recursion depth, and apply a conditionnal parallelisation of the loops at the first call of the function only. I tried that, it works (i.e. the results are correct), but the performances are terrible (much slower in multithread). What doesn't help here is that the workload is highly unbalanced between iteration, but even with balanced workloads it's terrible.

Comment: Actually no, it's not that terrible, I will post an answer...

Answer (score 0):

A general strategy in such cases would be to keep track of the recursion depth, and apply a conditionnal parallelisation of the loops at the first call of the function only.

The code in the question is incomplete, and doesn't even make sense (for instance `val` is determined from the last iteration only). So I've taken a working variation of it (and in Fortran).

First I tried:

```
integer recursive function recursion(size,flag,depth) result(val)
USE OMP_LIB
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: size, depth
logical, intent(in) :: flag

integer :: i, addval

val = 0
addval = 1; if (flag) addval = 2

!$OMP PARALLEL DO REDUCTION(+:val) SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1) IF(depth==0)
do i = 0, size-1
   val = val + addval + recursion(i, .not. flag, depth+1)
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

end function


program recurtest
USE OMP_LIB
implicit none

integer :: i
integer :: N = 28
double precision :: tic, toc
integer, external :: recursion

tic = omp_get_wtime()
    write(*,*) recursion(N,.false.,0)
toc = omp_get_wtime()
write(*,*) toc-tic

end program
```

But the performances were terrible, much slower than the sequential version. So I duplicated the code like this and it works much better:

```
if (depth==0) then
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO REDUCTION(+:val) SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1)
    do i = 0, size-1
        val = val + addval + recursion(i, .not. flag, depth+1)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
else
    do i = 0, size-1
        val = val + addval + recursion(i, .not. flag, depth+1)
    end do
end if
```

Fully sequential (initial call with depth=1, so that the parallel section is never used):

```
N=          28 result=   402653182
runtime=   2.1809919998049736
```

Running with 2 threads:

```
 N=          28 result=   402653182
 runtime=   1.4617079999297857
```

Running with 4 threads:

```
 N=          28 result=   402653182
 runtime=   1.2100369995459914
```

The speedup is not even 2x on 4 threads. The problem is that on this case the workload is highly unbalanced between iterations. `SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1)` helps a lot (otherwise there's no speed-up at all), but very likely no further speed-up will be obtained with more threads. By modifying the example to have balanced iterations (calling the recursion with `size-1` instead of `i, but of course the results are different...) I get a 3x speed-up on 4 threads (and it would likely scale better above 4 threads).

(compiled with gfortran 12)

## EDIT

I've come up with another version that takes into account that the last iteration has by far the highest workload. The `size-1`first iterations are parallelised at the first call, and the recursions are not further parallelised. The last iteration is parallelised at the next recursion level. The  initial call is with `omp=.true.`

```
integer recursive function recursion2(size,flag,omp) result(val)
USE OMP_LIB
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: size
logical, intent(in) :: flag, omp

integer :: i, addval

val = 0
addval = 1; if (flag) addval = 2

if (omp) then
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO REDUCTION(+:val) SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1)
    do i = 0, size-2
        val = val + addval + recursion2(i, .not. flag, .false.)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    if (size-1 >= 0) val = val + addval + recursion2(size-1, .not. flag, .true.)
else
    do i = 0, size-1
        val = val + addval + recursion2(i, .not. flag, .false.)
    end do
end if

end function
```

The speed-up improvement is not terrific, but it has maybe more chances to improve with more threads. With 4 threads:

```
 N=          28 result=   402653182
 runtime=   1.1320059997960925
```

Comment: I do not know Fortran, but try this C function: `int recursion(int size, int flag){ if (size==0) return 0; if (size==1) return flag+size; return 2*recursion(size-1, flag)+2-flag; }`

Comment: @Laci what's your point? I don't get it...

Comment: It gives the same result as your code but takes less than a microsecond.

Comment: @Laci maybe yes, but what does the particular function I am using, and whether it can be simplified without any loop or not, is not the point. You can imagine more complicated calculations, where suppressing the loop would not be easy or even possible. The exercise here, at least the way I have understood it, was *"how can we parallelize this kind of code involving a loop and a recursion inside the loop"*.

Comment: OK, that is why I asked the OP: "Is your goal to create a code as fast as possible or to learn OpenMP?", but no answer yet.